# Responsive website looks different on mobile than on thin desktop window

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, responsive-design

I'm making a responsive website and I've been testing it on Chrome on my computer. I can resize it, and it changes layout, etc. and look really good even when the screen is at its thinnest.

However, I tested the website out on my phone using Chrome and it doesn't look the same?

I have added this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

To the top of my HTML.

What is going wrong?

EDIT:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 475px) {

    #footer {
        height: 75px;
    }

    #left_footer,
    #right_footer {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #left_footer {
        bottom: 25px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any `@media` rules in your stylesheets?

Comment: Yeah, that's how I'm creating the responsive design.

Comment: @then please post your stylesheet. In fact, please post your project on jsfiddle.

Comment: Well, it's a personal website so I don't really want to post the whole thing, but see my edit for an example of the @media rules.

Comment: @user2397282 Take out your sites text and upload it

Answer (score 0):

You have a rather low max-width value there: many new smartphone phones have a high resolution screen. I generally start my mobile styling at 720 pixels or below.

Comment: I have lots of other @media rules, that was just an example.

Comment: The usual limit between smartphones and tablets is usually put at 768px (mainly because of the iPads, i guess). @TomMuller is right, this particular media query seems rather low on the max-width, so your device may not validate some of your rules you thought would be.

Comment: Again, this is just an example. I have @media queries starting from about 1200px.

Comment: In that case I don't think we can help with this one unless we know how it 'doesn't look the same'.